# How can i get values from this $scope using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting `selecteditems` in console like this

```
[{"model":"Lumia","brand":"Nokia","subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],"city":"Bangalore"}]
```

i stoed in $scope.details
    var selecteditems = $location.search().items;
        $scope.details =[{"model":"Lumia","brand":"Nokia","subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],"city":"Bangalore"}]

how can i get model and brand and subModel city in above variable

my expectation :

I have put like this but i am not getting value

```
console.log($scope.details.model);
```

I should get Lumia

```
console.log($scope.details.brand);
```

I should get  Nokia

```
console.log($scope.details.subModel);
```

I should get "Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `$scope.details` is an array, you will have to use index to get to the object which contains all the properties you want to access.

```
$scope.details[0].model
$scope.details[0].brand;
$scope.details[0].subModel;
```

This means you are accessing the first object in the array and then property model of that object.

Comment: i am getting undefined

Comment: when i pass directly is working
$scope.details =[{"model":"Lumia","brand":"Nokia","subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],"city":"Bangalore"}]

if i pass $scope.details =$location.search().items;
console.log($scope.details);
console i am getting value 
[{"model":"Lumia","brand":"Nokia","subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],"city":"Bangalore"}]

Comment: $scope.details =JSON.parse($location.search().items);

Comment: for this $scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 510,Lumia 735 TS"];
how can i get like this
$scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 510","Lumia 735 TS"];

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem. for your next question, you can do $scope.selectedlist[0].split(',').

Comment: no i want like this  $scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 510","Lumia 735 TS"];

Comment: Try console.log($scope.selectedlist[0].split(',')); this will give you wat you want

Comment: For more help you can mail me on ashfaqpatwari@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the values wrong.

You have 2 options, either change the data format or query the data properly.

First approach -> change the data format

```
$scope.details ={"model":"Lumia","brand":"Nokia","subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],"city":"Bangalore"}
```

This will allow you to get the values like

```
 $scope.details.model
```

Second approach, if you don't want to change the data format then:

```
$scope.details =[{"model":"Lumia","brand":"Nokia","subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],"city":"Bangalore"}]
```

You will get the values if you do this

```
console.log($scope.details[0].model) // value: Lumia.
```

You data is an array, so you have to pass the `index` before you can retrieve the JSON data.

Comment: i am getting undefined for 2nd condtion

Comment: You mean second solution? i double checked it and it is working. Please check it again

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to get value using key of the object. But actually `$scope.details` here is an array of object. Use this:

```
$scope.details[0].model;
$scope.details[0].brand;
$scope.details[0].subModel;
```

You can easily get the values of these.

Comment: $scope.details= $location.search().items;
    console.log($scope.details);console i am getting like this [{"model":"Lumia","brand":"Nokia","subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],"city":"Bangalore"}]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.forEach($scope.details, function(value,key){
   console.log(value.model);
   console.log(value.brand);
   console.log(value.subModel);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data look like this

```
$scope.details =[
  {
    "model":"Lumia",
    "brand":"Nokia",
    "subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],
    "city":"Bangalore"
  },
  {
    "model":"Galaxy",
    "brand":"Samsung",
    "subModel":["Galaxy S1","Galaxy S2", "Galaxy S3"],
    "city":"Bangalore"
  }
];
```

So you can do something like

```
$scope.details.forEach(function(item){
  console.log('Model: ', item.model);
  console.log('Brand: ', item.brand);
  console.log('subModel: ', item.subModel);
  console.log('city: ', item.city);
});
```

Comment: if i put $scope.details=$location.search().items;
    $scope.details.forEach(function(item){
  console.log('Model: ', item.model);
  console.log('Brand: ', item.brand);
  console.log('subModel: ', item.subModel);
  console.log('city: ', item.city);
}); getting error TypeError: $scope.details.forEach is not a function

Comment: it means that `$location.search().items` is not returning list and it your given sample data, it was list

Comment: console i am getting [{"model":"Lumia","brand":"Nokia","subModel":["Lumia 735 TS","Lumia 510"],"city":"Bangalore"}]

Comment: is is a string or list object

Comment: string with list object

Comment: Then you have to parse first, `JSON.parse(your_data)`

Comment: for this $scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 510,Lumia 735 TS"];
how can i get like this
$scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 510","Lumia 735 TS"];